# Explode a string into a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, split

Lets say I had a string like this.

apple:paper:red,pear:rock:blue,peach:scissors:green

How would you explode this into a multidimensional array?  Could you do a nested split loop?  Something like split the string on the comma and then again on the colon inside a loop.  How do you use explode in this manner?  I must be missing something obvious.  The end result should be something like.

[0][0] = apple [0][1] = pear [0][2] = peach

[1][0] = paper [1][1] = rock [1][2] = scissors

[2][0] = red [2][1] = blue [2][2] = green

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can call explode multiple times:

```
$string = 'apple:paper:red,pear:rock:blue,peach:scissors:green';
$result = array();
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $piece) {
    $result[] = explode(':', $piece);
}
```

Comment: This does split the string up into a 2d array, but the contents are not sorted out in the desired manner.  It ends up as "00 apple 01 paper 02 red" instead of "00 apple 01 pear 02 peach".  Is some sort of pre sort needed?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
$string = 'apple:paper:red,pear:rock:blue,peach:scissors:green';
foreach (explode(',', $string) as $key=>$piece) {
  foreach (explode(':', $piece) as $k=>$column) {
    $result[$key][$k] = $column;
  }
}
```

May help to make it come out as you want. (I've tested and it works for me ;))